# Fetch addedfile from dropZone on some button click and pass it to thymeleaf rest api as Post request

Tags: dropzone.js, spring-thymeleaf

I am new to webpage development and using thymeleaf & dropzone for one poc.
I would like to do following:

1. Upload a file from drop zone
2. On some button click ( not part of the dz form) fetch the addedfile and pass it to the rest api as Post body using thymeleaf to do rest of the operation on the uploaded file.

#1 is done and I am allowing single file only to get added via dz

Please guide with #2, I had tried to add th:onClick but it doesn't allow post method if it is not attached to the form and if I tried to add it in the form then getting error as MultipartFile object is not available.

Thanks